# Turn table contenteditable when tab key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a table entering tool, and I want to type items in when I press tab instead of having to click on each element. I was not able to figure out how to make that work, however.

```
$('table').on('mousedown objEvent.keyCode == 9', 'td', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var elementClass = $(this).attr('class');
  if (elementClass != "noedit") {
    $(event.target).closest('td').prop("contentEditable", true);
  }
```

I've tried mousedown and tab key and only mousedown worked.

```
$('table').on('focus', 'td', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var elementClass = $(this).attr('class');
  if (elementClass != "noedit") {
    $(event.target).closest('td').prop("contentEditable", true);
  }
```

Only mousedown worked this way as well.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vLsw0goe/

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you make items already editable before instead of applying it using jQuery? That would solve the problem easily, since you are not even removing it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('table').on('mousedown', 'td:not(.noedit)', function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    $(event.target).closest('td').prop("contentEditable", true);
});

$('table').on('keydown', 'td:not(.noedit)', function(event) {
    var i = $("td:not(.noedit)").index($(this));
    $("td:not(.noedit)").eq(i+1).trigger("mousedown");
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just have to add localstorage now!